# WebStorm/PHPStorm ES2015 autocomplete on this.get('object')

Tags: ember.js, autocomplete, phpstorm, webstorm

I'm using PHPStorm to develop an Ember application and I am looking for a way to enable code autocomplete on the .get() function so it will show me the functions on the appCache object.  For example, it'll show me the preLoadData() function.

This causes autocomplete, but it doesn't work quite right with Ember as Ember likes to use get('appCache') format:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    appCache: Ember.inject.service(),
    beforeModel(transition){
        this.appCache.preLoadData();
    }
});
```

This doesn't cause autocomplete, but does work in Ember.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    appCache: Ember.inject.service(),
    beforeModel(transition){
        this.get('appCache').preLoadData();
    }
});
```

Any ideas on how I can configure PHPStorm to make it autocomplete on the second example?

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately the IntelliJ IDEs simply don't have the capacity to do this (as far as I can tell from my 4 years of using them). It usually doesn't bug me too much, but if you want you could always submit a feature request for better Ember support. They have first-class support for Angular and React, so Ember might not be out of the question.

Comment: Thanks - I did notice that it if you get the child name right, it will find the declaration with a CTRL-Click, it's just the autocomplete that's not there yet.  I went over to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14919 and voted for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, it's not supported, but we can vote for it at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14919